# How to split paragraphs by specific starts and ends with specific rules by python re or something?

Tags: python, python-re

How to split paragraphs by specific starts and ends like this? Use python re or something?

```
Original_texts_with_paragraphs= """
0 zzzzz zzzz zzzzzzzz zzz GG G GGG
1 zzz AA zzz AAA zzzz zzz zzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzz
2 zzzzz AA zzz zzz AAA zzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzz
3 zzz zzzz zzz zzz zzzz zzzz zzz zzzz EE zzz EEE
4 zzz zzzz zzz zzz zzz zzzz zzz zzzz zzz zzzz zzz zzz
5 zz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zz zzz zzzzzz zzzz zzzz zzz
6 BBBB BB zzzz BBB zz B zzzzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zz
7 zzz zzz zzzz zzzz zzz zzzzz zzzz zzzzz zzzzz FF FFF zzz
8 CCCC zzz CCC zzzz zz zzzz zzzz zzz zzz GG G GGG
9 zzz AA zz AAA zzzz zzz zzz zzz FF zz FFF
10 AA zzzz AAA zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzzz zzzzz
11 zz CCCC zzz CCC zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zz
12 zzzz zzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzz zzzz EE zz EEE
13 zz zzz zzzz zzz zzz zzz 
14 zzz AA AAA zzz zzz zzzz zzzz GG zz GGG
15 BBBB BB BBB zz B zzzz zz GG zz G GGG
16 zzz  zzzz
17 zzzz zzz zzz  zzz
18 zz AA zzz AAA zzzz zzzz zzzz zzz
19 zzzz zzz zzz zzz zzzz zzzz zzzz GG G GGG
20 zzzz zzzzz zzzzzzzz zzz
21 zzzzz zzzz zzzzzzzz zzz GG G GGG
22 zzzzzz zzz zz zzzz
23 zzzzz AA zzz zzz AAA zzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzz
24 zzz zzzz zzz zzz zzzz zzzz zzz zzzz EE zzz EEE
"""
```

Starts:

```
Starts_with = """
AA AAA
BBBB BB BBB B
CCCC CCC
"""
```

Ends:

```
Ends_with = """
EE EEE
FF FFF
GG G GGG
"""
```

**Desired output:**

```
desired_output = """
1 zzz AA zzz AAA zzzz zzz zzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzz
2 zzzzz AA zzz zzz AAA zzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzz
3 zzz zzzz zzz zzz zzzz zzzz zzz zzzz EE zzz EEE


6 BBBB BB zzzz BBB zz B zzzzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zz
7 zzz zzz zzzz zzzz zzz zzzzz zzzz zzzzz zzzzz FF FFF zzz


8 CCCC zzz CCC zzzz zz zzzz zzzz zzz zzz GG G GGG


9 zzz AA zz AAA zzzz zzz zzz zzz FF zz FFF


10 AA zzzz AAA zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzzz zzzzz
11 zz CCCC zzz CCC zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zz
12 zzzz zzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzz zzzz EE zz EEE


14 zzz AA AAA zzz zzz zzzz zzzz GG zz GGG


15 BBBB BB BBB zz B zzzz zz GG zz G GGG


18 zz AA zzz AAA zzzz zzzz zzzz zzz
19 zzzz zzz zzz zzz zzzz zzzz zzzz GG G GGG


23 zzzzz AA zzz zzz AAA zzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzz
24 zzz zzzz zzz zzz zzzz zzzz zzz zzzz EE zzz EEE
"""
```

How to do that?

i tried this code but its not working well

```
import re

original = 'Original.txt'
new = 'Padded.txt'

Starts = (
    r'.*AA.*AAA.*',
    r'.*BBBB.*BB.*BBB.*B.*',
    r'.*CCCC.*CCC.*',
)

Ends = (
    r'.*EE.*EEE',
    r'.*FF.*FFF',
    r'.*GG.*G.*GGG'
)

desired_output = []


with open( original, 'r' ) as f:
    output = open( new, 'a+' )
    start = False

    for line in f:
        end = False

        for pattern in Starts:
            start_chars = line[:30]
            if re .search( pattern, start_chars ) != None:
                start = True

        for pattern in Ends:
            end_chars = line[-20:]
            if re .search( pattern, end_chars ) != None:
                start = False
                end = True

        if end:
            output .write( line +'\n\n' )
            desired_output .append(line +'\n\n')
        elif start:
            output .write( line )
            desired_output .append(line)

print(desired_output)
```

i tried it lot but i still confused it spliting paragraphs. My main purpose is split paragraphs by specific starts and ends. I have lists of starts and ends.

> I also need to store rest of lines into other list. for use it
> later.

please help me?

Comment: The logic for split is not clear. I don't understand question

Comment: @root163 which part is tricky? i will explain it for you

Comment: `Starts_with` -- does it mean we need to find the exact value in `Original_texts_with_paragraphs ` and replace it with `---------------------------------------------
\n`?

Comment: --------------------------------------------- its nothing just for spliting paragraphs (mark). it replaces nothing. please don't care about it

Comment: i will delete it then you can understand easily

Comment: Shouldn't the lines 8 and 9 be in the same paragraph for the same reason the lines 6 and 7 are in the desired output?

Comment: @enzo if you see carefully there is 'Starts_with ' and 'Ends_with ' in lines 8 and 9.        
For lines 6,7 there are also with 'Starts_with ' and 'Ends_with '.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thx @Doyousketch2.
i edited your code then it works better.

```
try:
    file = open("Padded1.txt","r+")
    file.truncate(0)
    file.close()
except:
    pass

import re

original = 'Original1.txt'
new = 'Padded1.txt'

result = []

with open( original, 'r' ) as f:
    output = open( new, 'a+' )
    start = False

    for line in f:
        end = False

        for pattern in Starts:
            start_chars = line[:30]
            if re .search( pattern, start_chars ) != None:
                start = True

        for pattern in Ends:
            end_chars = line[-20:]
            if re .search( pattern, end_chars ) != None:
                #####start = False
                end = True

        if end and start:  
            output .write( line +'\n\n\n' )
            result.append(line +'\n\n\n')
            start = False
            end = False
            
        elif start:
            output .write( line )
            result.append(line)
            end = False
output.close()

if start == True and end == False:
    #remove last line from a text line in python
    fd=open("Padded1.txt","r")
    d=fd.read()
    fd.close()
    sep = "\n\n\n\n"
    s=sep.join(d.split(sep)[:-1])
    fd=open("Padded1.txt","w+")
    for i in range(len(s)):
        fd.write(s[i])
    fd.close()
    
elif start == False and end == True:
    #remove last line from a text line in python
    fd=open("Padded1.txt","r")
    d=fd.read()
    fd.close()
    sep = "\n\n\n\n"
    s=sep.join(d.split(sep)[:-1])
    fd=open("Padded1.txt","w+")
    for i in range(len(s)):
        fd.write(s[i])
    fd.close()



# Comparing Two Text Files, Removing the duplicate lines, and Writing results to a new text file

small_file = open('Original1.txt','r')
long_file = open('Padded1.txt','r')
output_file = open('output_file.txt','w')

try:
    small_lines = small_file.readlines()
    small_lines_cleaned = [line.rstrip().lower() for line in small_lines]
    long_file_lines = long_file.readlines()
    long_lines_cleaned = [line.rstrip().lower() for line in long_file_lines]

    for line in small_lines_cleaned:
        if line not in long_lines_cleaned:
            output_file.writelines(line + '\n')

finally:
    small_file.close()
    long_file.close()
    output_file.close()
    
print('Done')
```

Answer (score 0):

It follows very similar logic to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68073949/how-to-split-a-text-file-into-smaller-files-based-on-regex-pattern/) answered moments ago.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import re

original = 'Original.txt'
new = 'Padded.txt'

Starts = (
    r'AA .+',
    r'BBBB BB.+BBB.+B',
    r'CCCC .+ CCC',
)

Ends = (
    r'EE .+ EEE',
    r'FF.+FFF',
    r'.+ GGG'
)

with open( original, 'r' ) as f:
    output = open( new, 'a+' )
    start = False

    for line in f:
        end = False

        for pattern in Starts:
            start_chars = line[:25]
            if re .search( pattern, start_chars ) != None:
                start = True

        for pattern in Ends:
            end_chars = line[-15:]
            if re .search( pattern, end_chars ) != None:
                start = False
                end = True

        if end:  output .write( line +'\n' )
        elif start:  output .write( line )
```

> 1 zzz AA zzz AAA zzzz zzz zzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzz
> 2 zzzzz AA zzz zzz AAA zzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzz
> 3 zzz zzzz zzz zzz zzzz zzzz zzz zzzz EE zzz EEE
>
> 6 BBBB BB zzzz BBB zz B zzzzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zz
> 7 zzz zzz zzzz zzzz zzz zzzzz zzzz zzzzz zzzzz FF FFF zzz
>
> 8 CCCC zzz CCC zzzz zz zzzz zzzz zzz zzz GG G GGG
>
> 9 zzz AA zz AAA zzzz zzz zzz zzz FF zz FFF
>
> 10 AA zzzz AAA zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzzz zzzzz
> 11 zz CCCC zzz CCC zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zz
> 12 zzzz zzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzz zzzz EE zz EEE
>
> 13 zz AA zzz
> 14 AAA zzz zzz zzzz zzzz GG zz GGG
>
> 15 BBBB BB BBB zz B GG zz G
> 16 zzz GGG

Comment: its not splited correctly. supposed to replace lines 4, 5, 17 and line 8 is separated.

Comment: OK well, same idea...  Just have to loop through those as well.  Lemme get some tea first.

Comment: i think your code is only check 2 elements max. how to check BBBB BB BBB B of every elements in order? i mean how to edit this line  r'BBBB .* BBB', to  BBBB BB BBB B all elements by order.

Comment: why this code only check 2 elements? i mean  r'BBBB .* BBB', what is the meaning of this?. i need whole elements. please help me

Comment: It's a [regex pattern](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).  It only scans the first few characters for patterns that match in the beginning, that's what you asked for.  The dot just skips a few chars to look for the next match.  Try `r'BBBB BB.*BBB.*B'` if it needs to be more exact.

Comment: start_chars = line[:20] and end_chars = line[-12:] why you add that specific?

Comment: Well it was a guess.  You had lines like "BBBB BB BBB zz B" so I wanted to limit the search to the first 20 characters of the line so it doesn't keep searching for start patterns in the middle or end of each line. You could make that `line[:25]` or similar, if need be.  --  Same for the end matches.  You don't want to hunt for "EE zzz EEE" near the beginning of the line, or else you might get false-positives.  So those are restricted to the last 12 characters.

Comment: so how to save lines 4, 5, and 17 ?  its spare for me

Comment: Oh to what, another file?  or just write them to the bottom of that one?

Comment: another file is better. for use it later.

Comment: please check my question again. i edited for you. please see the desired output part

Comment: i tested your code. but output is not like desired output