# regex long texts sequence and many .* problem in python

Tags: python, regex

I have long sequence inputs like this. And i tried [Catastrophic Backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). but can't fix my long sequence input.
i mean this code will stuck after few iteration in for loop. Do you have any idea about my mistake in **Starts_2dugaar_heseg** ?

or any other way to do that like regex?

```
Starts_2dugaar_heseg = (
        r'.*Нэхэмжлэгч.*шүүх.*хуралдаанд.*гаргасан.*тайлбартаа:.*',
        r'.*Нэхэмжлэгч.*болон.*нэхэмжлэгчийн.*итгэмжлэгдсэн.*төлөөлөгч.*шүүхэд.*гаргасан.*нэхэмжлэл.*болон.*шүүх.*хуралдаанд.*гаргасан.*тайлбартаа:.*',
        r'.*Нэхэмжлэгч.*болон.*нэхэмжлэгчийн.*итгэмжлэгдсэн.*төлөөлөгч,.*өмгөөлөгч.*нар.*шүүхэд.*гаргасан.*нэхэмжлэл.*болон.*шүүх.*хуралдаанд.*гаргасан.*нэхэмжлэлдээ:.*',
        r'.*Нэхэмжлэгч.*болон.*нэхэмжлэгчийн.*өмгөөлөгч.*шүүхэд.*гаргасан.*нэхэмжлэл.*болон.*шүүх.*хуралдаанд.*гаргасан.*тайлбартаа:.*',
        r'.*Нэхэмжлэгч.*болон.*төлөөлөгч.*шүүхэд.*гаргасан.*нэхэмжлэл.*болон.*шүүх.*хуралдаанд.*гаргасан.*тайлбартаа:.*',
        r'.*Нэхэмжлэгч.*болон.*түүний.*итгэмжлэгдсэн.*төлөөлөгч.*шүүхэд.*гаргасан.*нэхэмжлэл,.*шүүх.*хуралдаанд.*гаргасан.*тайлбартаа:.*',
        r'.*Нэхэмжлэгч.*болон.*түүний.*итгэмжлэгдсэн.*төлөөлөгч.*шүүхэд.*гаргасан.*нэхэмжлэлдээ:.*',
        r'.*Нэхэмжлэгч.*гаргасан.*нэхэмжлэл.*болон.*шүүх.*хуралдаанд.*гаргасан.*тайлбартаа:.*',
        r'.*Нэхэмжлэгч.*итгэмжлэгдсэн.*төлөөлөгч.*шүүх.*хуралдаанд.*гаргасан.*тайлбартаа:.*',
        r'.*Нэхэмжлэгч.*итгэмжлэгдсэн.*төлөөлөгч.*шүүх.*хуралдаанд.*тайлбарлахдаа:.*',
        r'.*Нэхэмжлэгч.*итгэмжлэгдсэн.*төлөөлөгч.*шүүхэд.*гаргасан.*нэхэжмлэлийн.*шаардлагадаа:.*',
        r'.*Нэхэмжлэгч.*итгэмжлэгдсэн.*төлөөлөгч.*шүүхэд.*гаргасан.*нэхэмжлэл.*болон.*нэхэмжлэгч.*шүүх.*хуралдаанд.*гаргасан.*тайлбартаа:.*',
        r'.*Нэхэмжлэгч.*итгэмжлэгдсэн.*төлөөлөгч.*шүүхэд.*гаргасан.*нэхэмжлэл.*болон.*шүүх.*хуралдаанд.*гаргасан.*тайлбар:.*',
        r'.*Нэхэмжлэгч.*итгэмжлэгдсэн.*төлөөлөгч.*шүүхэд.*гаргасан.*нэхэмжлэл.*болон.*шүүх.*хуралдаанд.*гаргасан.*тайлбартаа:.*',
        r'.*Нэхэмжлэгч.*итгэмжлэгдсэн.*төлөөлөгч.*шүүхэд.*гаргасан.*нэхэмжлэлд.*болон.*шүүх.*хуралдаанд.*гаргасан.*тайлбарт:.*',
        r'.*Нэхэмжлэгч.*итгэмжлэгдсэн.*төлөөлөгч.*шүүхэд.*гаргасан.*нэхэмжлэлдээ:.*',
        r'.*Нэхэмжлэгч.*итгэмжлэгдсэн.*төлөөлөгч.*шүүхэд.*гаргасан.*нэхэмжлэлийн.*шаардлага.*болон.*шүүх.*хуралдаанд.*гаргасан.*тайлбартаа:.*',
        r'.*Нэхэмжлэгч.*итгэмжлэгдсэн.*төлөөлөгч.*шүүхэд.*гаргасан.*нэхэмжлэлээ.*дэмжиж.*шүүх.*хуралдаанд.*тайлбарлахдаа:.*',
        r'.*Нэхэмжлэгч.*нь.*нэхэмжлэлийн.*өөрчилсөн.*шаардлагадаа:.*',
        r'.*Нэхэмжлэгч.*нэхэмжлэгч.*нар.*шүүхэд.*гаргасан.*нэхэмжлэлдээ:.*',
        r'.*Нэхэмжлэгч.*нэхэмжлэл.*болон.*шүүх.*хуралдаан.*дээр.*гаргасан.*тайлбартаа:.*',
        r'.*Нэхэмжлэгч.*нэхэмжлэл.*болон.*шүүх.*хуралдаанд.*гаргасан.*тайлбартаа:.*',
        r'.*Нэхэмжлэгч.*нэхэмжлэлийн.*шаардлагаа.*дэмжиж.*шүүх.*хуралдаанд.*гаргасан.*тайлбартаа:.*',
        r'.*Нэхэмжлэгч.*нэхэмжлэлийн.*шаардлагаа.*өөрчилж.*гаргахдаа:.*',
        r'.*Нэхэмжлэгч.*нэхэмжлэлийн.*шаардлагаа.*өөрчлөн.*шүүхэд.*гаргасан.*тайлбартаа:.*',
        r'.*Нэхэмжлэгч.*нэхэмжлэлийн.*шаардлагыг.*тодруулахдаа.*болон.*шүүх.*хуралдаанд.*тайлбарлахдаа:.*',
        r'.*Нэхэмжлэгч.*өмгөөлөгч.*шүүх.*хуралдаанд.*гаргасан.*тайлбартаа:.*',
        r'.*Нэхэмжлэгч.*тал.*шүүх.*хуралдаанд.*гаргасан.*нэхэмжлэлийн.*тайлбартаа.*',
        r'.*шүүхэд.*нэхэмжлэлийн.*шаардлагаа.*нэмэгдүүлэх.*болон.*өөрчлөн.*гаргахдаа:.*'
    )


for pattern in Starts_2dugaar_heseg:
                    start_chars = line[:250]            
                    if re .search( pattern, start_chars ) != None:
                        start = True
                        print('start = True')
```

> there is a regex Catastrophic Backtracking problem on these long
> sequence input. Any idea about how to prevent total stuck in for loop.
> because i used to many **.*** in my sequence. but its necessary to add..

Comment: or any other way to that like regex?

Comment: Since you are using `search`, the `.*` at the beginning and end of each string are pointless and will just slow things down.

Comment: @TimRoberts your right. if i remove .* at start and end then it saves some computition. But i need to save lot of computation. Do you have any extra suggestion about it?

Comment: Are these all going to be separate words?  If so, then you could match whitespace or a word boundary before and after instead of literally looking for anything.  Do these words actually have to be in this order?  Can you find a way to splitting your text into words and do word matching instead?

Comment: @TimRoberts problem is this all look like this. i mean word order also important and may can be some other words in between my words. its some kind of search engine..

Comment: @TimRoberts please see this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68077432/how-to-split-paragraphs-by-specific-starts-and-ends-with-specific-rules-by-pytho

Comment: @TimRoberts "Can you find a way to splitting your text into words and do word matching instead?"  No can't suffle words. because if i suffle words then sentence context will disrupt.

Answer (score 0):

i found solution using:

```
re.compile()
```